# Why I can't install google play services maps (Android) , in VS 2015?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget

every time , I try to install google play services maps (Android) , in VS 2015

I find it on components - but with (Incomplete) and can't use it , check the below image ..

[image]

I searched for another solution to install it using nuget , but I always have this error message

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Could not install package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 42.1001.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

How to get it work ?

Answer (score 4):

Update your Xamarin installation / project to use `MonoAndroid 7.0`, as it is required by the latest "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" package. As of the error message, you currently have MonoAndroid 5.0

**Updated**
To update your installation, inside Visual Studio go to the menu `Tools -> Options`, and then head over `Xamarin -> Other -> Check now`, and then follow the instructions.

After that, check your android project: right click on it -> then "Properties", then go to the "Application" tab and on "Target android version" you should have the installed SDKs, and 7.0 there. (I leave to always use the latest version). To check the xamarin version installed, go to the menu "Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio", and then search for the Xamarin component there... is should show 7.0

Comment: How to Update my Xamarin installation / project to use MonoAndroid 7.0 ?

Comment: Xamarin for visual studio is up to date!
-- then ?

Comment: Check your android project: right click on it -> then "Properties", then go to the "Application" tab and on "Target android version" you should have the installed SDKs, and 7.0 there. (I leave to always use the latest version). To check the xamarin version installed, go to the menu "Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio", and then search for the Xamarin component there... is should show 7.0

Comment: I already converted the target SDK version to 7.0.0 (nougat)

but also it release the same error and see it (version 5)

I should change it on another place , right ?

Comment: another question , is this will affect on the minimum SDK version supported on the mobile phone - (I want to support the old devices , OK?)

Comment: Just to make sure, create a new test project from the scratch and see if it works.